# How show hh:mm in TextView?

Tags: android, textview, string-formatting

I want show time in TextView using below code.

```
PersianCalendar persianCalendar = new PersianCalendar();
            persianCalendar.setTime(mDate);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(mDate);
            holder.tvTime.setText(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

Problem occurs when time is for example `12:03` in TextView displayed as `12:3`

How can I fix this?

Comment: see `java.util.Formatter` documentation

Comment: One way would be to use `String.format`: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)

Comment: or just use `holder.tvTime.setText(String.format("%tR", cal))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can format a Date to a String like this (using java.text.SimpleDateFormat)

```
holder.tvTime.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm").format(mDate));
```

The `H` format specifier means Hour in day (0-23), and the `mm` means Minute in hour with two digits.

See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for other formatting options.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to format minute in 2 digits..

```
      holder.tvTime.setText(String.format("%d:%02d",cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

**Edit** - As suggested by @henry.. you can directly go with this.. `holder.tvTime.setText(String.format("%d:%02d",cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));`

Comment: Why not producing the whole string in one go with a format like `"%d:%02d"`

Comment: @Henry why not `"%tR"`?

Comment: @pskink Yes, yet another way of doing it. Put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and solved by this.
Probably it is not the best solution, but it worked for me.

```
PersianCalendar persianCalendar = new PersianCalendar();
            persianCalendar.setTime(mDate);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(mDate);

            String minuteSelected = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            String minutWith0 = ((minuteSelected.length() == 1 ? "0" + minuteSelected : minuteSelected));// to get minut "01" insted of "1"


holder.tvTime.setText(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+ minutWith0);
```